# one program runs on multiple JVMs?

Tags: java, jvm, distributed-computing

I know that MPI does it, also heard that Erlang has nice support for this. But is there any similar frameworks/languages on JVM? I need to run one program distributed on multiple machines transparently.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "classic" solution for this is [Terracotta Cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terracotta_Cluster), which provides JVM-level objects distributed across a cluster, where "cluster" means distribution across a network, not just across processes.

It's open-source (or bits of it are, anyway), but I have no personal experience of it. It's impressive technology, though.

Answer (score 3):

Also been hearing good things about [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/), also open source, though I'm not sure it is transparent like Terracotta.  On the flip side, if it isn't transparent it means it is not enhancing byte code which some people prefer to avoid due to stack traces no longer lining up with the source.

Comment: Thank you. first time heard of this. I will definitely check it out.

Comment: It's new on the scene.  Lot's of buzz about it.  Hoping to check it out myself at some point.